# Is there a quality-saving photo zoom plugin for GIMP?

Tags: gimp

For Photoshop there is Genuine Fractals plugin to increase image resolution with very little loss in visual quality. Is there an analogue for GIMP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Go to [this page](http://gimpfx-foundry.sourceforge.net/browse26/egger-stair-Interpolation.html)
- Right click the download link on the top right corner and click Save As and save the file somewhere.

[image]

- Then browse to your home folder and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.
- Now navigate to .gimp-2.6 or .gimp-2.7 and then go to the scripts folder and copy and paste the downloaded file

[image]

- Now launch GIMP,you will find a new menu FX-Foundry,now select Eg Stair Scaleup
  [image]
- Now you can enlarge or shrink the image with the dialog presented.
  [image]

Comment: these are install instructions for *something*. what is it and how does it compare to the product in the question?

Comment: @vbence It is a quality-saving photo zoom plugin for GIMP.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know in Gimp is to use **Image>>Scale**

[image]

Comment: Of course I know of this feature, but it isn't any of that good. "Genuine Fractals" Photoshop plugin can stretch a picture for more than 200% without notable visual degradation (try using standard toolswith cubic/bicubic interpolation for this and see the difference). I am just curious if free software world has produced something of this power (may it even be not very user-friendly).

Comment: Such thing is not available for GIMP yet.

Answer (score 0):

There are new advanced interpolation algorithms in works for GEGL, the new GIMP's core. Some of them are designed with upscaling in mind. This will be available in GIMP some time after release of 2.8.

Answer (score 0):

One can also try this plugin  http://liquidrescale.wikidot.com/en:start
this also seems to be working in steps (as the first answer)

Its also been reported that gimp can do this without extra plugins

Open the image you want to resize in Gimp. Simply go to Image » Scale Image. Enter your desired dimensions. Under the Quality section choose Sinc (Lanczos3) as Interpolation method and click on the Scale Image button.

Last methods is probably not as optimal as other mentioned methods

Answer (score -1):

The GIMP doesn't have anything like this, but there is a freeware Windows program that has a fractal scaling plugin. Look up Meesoft Image Analyzer. The fractal plugin is a bit buggy, and is offered separately. Usually it works fine, but if it throws out an error, you can usually just try again and get it to work. It is kinda slow, though.

I'd give you a link, but I don't want to run into any spam filters. I hate that we can't just use the GIMP, but at least it's something. I've not tried it on WINE yet, but there's nothing about the program that should break it.

BTW, it will also do spline-based interpolation. Heck, that's the reason I originally found the program. Once I discovered it could also do fractal-based scaling, I figured I'd better spread the news to the other sites I found while looking.

Comment: The OP isn't looking for a Windows plugin.